# Listings: Prevent keyword highlighting in Javascript comments

Tags: listings, code, javascript

I use the `listings` package to display code snippets in my documents. To add syntax highlighting to my javascript listings, I have defined javascript as language for the listings package. The keywords I defined will be highlighted even if they appear within comments. How can I prevent this?

Minimum working example for my language definition:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{javascript}{
   morekeywords=[1]{if},
   morecomment=[l]//,
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   commentstyle=\color{green},
}
```

Example listing:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=javascript] 
// if 
\end{lstlisting}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Desired output:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Did you figure out the solution to this problem?

Comment: No, not really. As a workaround I removed the `if` from the keywords list and added it as literate:

`literate={if}{{{\color{blue}if}}}{3}`

Answer (score -1):

I tried this in Overleaf, and it works. For solution see:
https://www.overleaf.com/read/zrxjfjvvbghj.
Please note that I added the curly brackets, i.e.: `morecomment=[l]{//}`.
However, I also tried this without them and it works fine.

**Update:**
The package seems to figure out how to overcome this error. Unfortunately, I cannot determine what the cause was.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/243774)